# jQuery to click on image and show a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

I am now working on a image slice show in order to view some product images.

First, I will have some small thumbnails and by clicking on the thumbnails, a larger image will be shown in another div, with default displaying the img1's big image.

Then if the user hover on the big image, the cursor image will change to a magnifying glass (zoomin.cur) and if the user clicked on the big image, another div (class="detailview-container-bg) will show on top of everything. In the hidden div, small thumbnail images are placed on the top and a large image will show in the lower part, with img1 as the default display.

Up to now, I have come up with the first click on thumbnail to display a larger image and I get stuck on change cursor and second click to show the hidden div. I have built some jQuery for the second click but it does not containing errors and I don't know why it is not working to show the div.

```
        $(function(){
            $('#primaryImageDisplay').on("click",function(){
                $('#productSlide').css({'display':'absolute'});
            });
        })
```

I have concluded my code in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sammmmi/hbh7boyf/1/) and may you please give me some ideas on it. Thank you so much for your time ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use proper value for display.  ( e.g. block http://learnlayout.com/display.html )
the value absolute comes from css property 'position'

If you debug your code, you'll notice that the display property is not updated with the value absolute.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the stupid mistake I didn't realized that.... Thank you so much for your reminder!!!!!

Comment: No problem, “Anyone who has never made a mistake has never tried anything new.” ― Albert Einstein

Answer (score 0):

I added the source link for jquery. You can use all of these actions within the some document function. I have included a sample below.

You can just use the show()/hide() or the slideToggle() methods instead of changing css. It displays better and works better across devices.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#desktopThumb1').on("click",function(){
   $('#primaryImageDisplay').attr("src","img1.jpg");});

   $('#desktopThumb2').on("click",function(){      
   $('#primaryImageDisplay').attr("src","img2.jpeg");});

   $('#desktopThumb3').on("click",function(){                     
   $('#primaryImageDisplay').attr("src","img3.jpeg");});

   $('#desktopThumb4').on("click",function(){
   $('#primaryImageDisplay').attr("src","img4.jpeg");});

    $("#primaryImageDisplay").click(function(){
    $("#productSlide").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason you have to code this yourself? It sounds like you are looking for quite an advanced gallery on your site.

Might I suggest http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ ?

Its a great tool, I have used it on many sites.

Comment: thank you for your suggesution but i need to code it on my own!